# Is there a way to read a string into the Jackson API to easily get back a JSON object

Tags: java, json, jackson

Is there was a way to pass a String into some Jackson object and have it populate the JSON obj for me?  Maybe I'm comparing apples to oranges but the json-rpc-1.0.jar library allows me to do this:

```
// string will be read in from file but putting the string below just to show what i'm trying to do.
JSONObject jsonObj; 
String testStr = "{"blah":123, "aaa": "got here", "foo":"bar", "bar":123}";
jsonObj = new JSONObject(testStr);
jsonObj.put("blah",345);
```

If I execute

```
System.out.println(jsonObj);
```

I get:

```
{"blah":345, "aaa": "got here", "foo":"bar", "bar":123}
```

The problem with the json-rpc-1.0.jar file is it doesn't play nicely with `long` primitive types.  For some reason, it converts long data to something like 1.32e9 if I tried to assign a timestamp (long data type) to a field.

I found Jackson (jackson-core-2.2.3.jar) is nicer to longs, preserving the 10-13 digits I need for my timestamp.  However, I can't find anything that works like the above snippet of code in Jackson.  The closest might be ObjectMapper.readValue but it's not exactly like above.

Please let me know if this is possible or if I'm just dreaming.  Thanks in advance for your help.  In the meantime, I will try to look at the API some more.

Comment: Please format your `String` correctly.

Comment: my bad, I'm reading the string in from a file so the string is not going to be read in from the program like this.  i'll change the description a little.  thx for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO this is not how Jackson is meant to be used. With Jackson, an object should be serialized with the fields of its class. You shouldn't be adding anything to that JSON afterwards. For the sake of the question, however, here's what you can do. Take for example

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MyClass a = new MyClass();
    ObjectNode node = mapper.<ObjectNode>valueToTree(a);
    node.put("blah", "123");
    System.out.println(node);
}

static class MyClass {
    private String value = "some text";
    private long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

which prints

```
{"value":"some text","timestamp":1384233053765,"blah":"123"}
```

The `valueToTree()` method will convert your object into an `ObjectNode` which is kind of a tree that holds the various JSON elements. You can modify this `ObjectNode` by adding or removing elements. That is what we do with `node.put("blah", "123");`. It will add a Json object with name `blah` and value `"123"`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and answer.  I guess I'm looking for something like json-rpc because there are several json objects that will be coming in from the file and they aren't all uniform in content.  They will all have this timestamp field which I'll be looking for.  Having some rigid class for me to define may not work in this case.  I'll keep your answer in mind when I do get to work with uniform json objects in a file.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Classified Consider checking out [Java API for JSON](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html) too.